# How to calculate relative entropy of coherence?

Tags: relative-entropy

Relative entropy of coherence for a density matrix p is defined as follow

$C(p)=S(p_{diag})-S(p)$

Where S is the von neumann entropy.

for more info check the [link](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-09332-9) (look at the section result)

I know how to calculate the von neumann entropy. I just dont know how to calculate $p_{diag}$?

I tried using the diagonal elements of p to obtain  $p_{diag}$ but the result of C(p) became over 1. I think C(p) is in range 0 to 1. Isnt it?